# Finding a function to match a given graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to draw a curved graph as in **[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKM2b.png)** using the below function. But I got **[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0peW.png)**. How I can able to get exactly like **[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKM2b.png)** curve? :|

Sorry, I'm not good at Maths, so I just added my function below instead of the maths part. I just need the Maths part only, I'll convert it to the code :)

```
generateDummyData() {
  //       x  y
  rows = [[0, 0]];

  for (let i = 0; i < 8E3; i++) {
    rows.push([i, Math.floor(Math.log(i) * 32000)]);
  }

}
```

**Image 1** *(What I expect)*
[image]
**Image 2** *(What I got)*
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: It looks a bit like the [inverse tangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html).

Comment: @Blue I'm not sure how to do it. :(

Comment: For instance, $y=200 \operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)$ agrees at $(0,0)$. For $x=200$, it gives $y\approx 221$. It levels-off at $314.159\ldots$ (aka, $100\pi$), though. (I consider this a bonus! :)  You can play with $y=a \operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)$ to see if you get anything closer to what you want. Another thing to try is something like $y=a(1-\exp(-bx))$.

Comment: looks like charging of a capacitor with large time constant. You may try modifying R, C values in 
 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3myhlifwhl